# alternative to do {} while(false) for macros

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
#define myMacro()   \
    {               \
        macro stuff \
    } ((void)0)
```

Isn't this better than a `do {} while(false)` construct? there is no branch and compile time should be faster - and still everything is scoped and it requires a semicolon after it - seems perfect to me!

So are there any drawbacks or is this really superior to do/while?

Comment: In which way this should be superior to the `do {} while(false)` version again?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for `if else` statements

Comment: @tangrs Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ compile time - especially when there are 100 such constructs in a single function - once I optimized the compile time of a project from 30 minutes to 2 minutes (YES! x15) by rewriting a macro to not have ```do {} while(false)``` in it (compiler: MSVC in Release)

Comment: @PcAF it requires a semicolon and it is a no-op - and the compiler doesn't issue a warning about it

Comment: @PcAF: He added the `((void)0)` to make a final semi-colon required, just like a normal statement that ends with a semi-colon.

Comment: The main drawback is that it doesn't always work in circumstances where `do {} while(false)` does.   Try `if(any_valid_expression) myMacro(); else {}`.

Comment: I'm really surprised by the performance increase.  Is that with optimization on (/Ot)?  Anyway, if the performance gain is worthwhile, you can still use it with the proper comments

Comment: @stefaanv OP answered that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37678909/alternative-to-do-whilefalse-for-macros/37678994?noredirect=1#comment62835376_37678994). Apparently the macro was being expanded 500 times in a function...

Comment: Okay, it's about compiler times.  Fair enough. Having to wait 30 minutes for the compiler to finish is hardly acceptable these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your alternative construct does not work for `if else` statements.

```
void test() {
    if (1)
        myMacro();
    else
        myMacro();
}
```

Compiler error:

```
error: expected expression
        else
        ^
1 error generated.
```

That being said, most optimising compilers should recognise the `do { } while(0)` pattern and optimise it away. I'm not sure what code base you're compiling that would have a 15 times speedup from replacing these constructs.

Comment: indeed the compiler optimizes the loop away - but it is more work in order to optimize it away - it generates a more complex AST before the optimizations kick in.

and only MSVC gave me the huge compile time slowdown - the problem was in one big function which called the macro 500x times and depending on the compiler (MSVC...) it could be very slow. Note that if the macro was used x1000 times it wasn't 2 times slower but much much more - it seemed exponential in compile times.

Comment: The question is, why is the macro being expanded 500 times in the function?

Comment: well it was a macro that registered attributes on an object using the Autodesk Maya API... and there were **many** attributes to be registered. We couldn't figure out an easy way to iterate over them because there were many differences and actually different macros were used - but they all had the ```do {} while(false)``` construct in them

Answer (score -1):

I use `do-while-false` specifically so that I can `break;` out of it:

```
do
{
   if (Step1() == false) break;
   if (Step2() == false) break;
   if (DoMoreWork() == false) break;
} while (0);
```

You ***cannot*** break out of a block that is not part of a loop. (`for`, `do-while`, `do-while`, `switch`).

So I consider that a drawback to your macro, and why I prefer the `do-while-false`.

Comment: well I didn't ask in the context of early breaks - but in the context of safe macros - such that will not break when used with an ```if``` and etc.